# fur rendering: unwanted fur under not emitting geometry

Tags: particles

Good Day.
I am realizing the attached 3d model in Blender 2.93.5LTS, and for various and different fur types I am using geometry parts cloned from main geometry, then separated and that were after shrinked, so they stay under main geometry. Subsequently, I applied a different type of fur particles for each geometry part. Then, when rendering, I’ve noticed that on the beak and on the arms appear fur strands, but under that parts there is no generating geometry at all... Each fur generating geometry part has origin set to geometry center of mass, and each part has a subdivision modifier applied. Someone knows what is happening?[image: image: marked in red the unwanted fur]

Comment: Please share just a beak with us to see your blend setup. Use https://blend-exchange.com/ and copy &paste given code via edit into your Question. It looks like vertex weight is not zero, but like 0.0xy.

Comment: The main geometry itself has a hair particle emitter connected. I have retried the rendering and now there is no faults.